# How to automatically assign a worker for message processing?

Tags: node.js, load-balancing, worker

After the master has forked the workers and now wants to start sending messages to the worker processes, is specifying a worker before sending a message the only way to pass the message? The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_send_message_sendhandle_callback)  suggests so.

```
const worker = cluster.fork();
worker.send('hi there');
```

If yes, what is the [scheduling policy](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_schedulingpolicy) all about? Is there a way where we could:

```
master.sendToWorker('Hi there!');
```

and it automatically selects the worker according to the default/configured algorithm?

Comment: I am pretty sure there exists code snippets about it but you could certainly create a simple solution in a couple lines.

Comment: I've tried my best at answering, but been pretty vague as I didn't know the target goal of this messaging you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheduling policy is for handling incoming connections. If you have 3 workers that are express applications, when a user connects, only one worker will handle the request. It will either be Round Robin, by default, or OS's choice. So that does not give you lots of flexibility.

Now, that does not help us on your request, which is to send messages from the master. The correct solution depends on the nature of the message you'd like to send.

If you are sending a message to make the worker start a task, messages might not be the best solution, you might like to use a job queue instead. But if you'd like to use messages anyways, your master could simply take note of available workers and arbitrarily send the message to a free one, removing it from the available workers until it reports to have finished.

You could simply use your round robin implementation, in one line of code it would look like this:

```
workersList[++messageCount%workersList.length].send("message");
```

If you wanted to use the native policy, you could have your workers listen on a specific port and have your master send a message to that port on localhost, it should work, but you'll have to implement your own messaging system...

IMO, if you want to send a message, you know who you want to send it to. If you want to send a message to a "random" recipient, it may be because a message might not be the appropriate way to communicate for that scenario.